# How to calculate age based on one parameter function?

Tags: javascript, function

I'm learning javascript and I need to write a simple function that will display my age, based on my birth year.  The only parameter I can use is the year I was born and I need to call the function.  This is what I have so far:

```
function myAge(birthYear) {
    var Year = new Date().getFullYear();
    return Year() - (birthYear);
}
myAge(1984);
```

I'm receiving the error code that it is not a function, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I thought I could call the function at the end with the numerical year and that it would calculate.  Any help or advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Right, year is a number, so you should remove the '()' and try again

Comment: You have a typo: `return Year - (birthYear);`

Comment: More references at https://codepen.io/tipsoftheday/pen/hwFde. I recommended read many example in codepen.io if you newbies javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have a typo in your function, instead of the line,

```
return Year() - (birthYear);
```

write,

```
return (Year - birthYear);
```

Here is the complete updated function,

```
function myAge(birthYear) {
    var Year = new Date().getFullYear();
    return (Year - birthYear);
}
console.log(myAge(1984));
```

Comment: Thank you!  I've been staring at it so long that I didn't notice.  It's still returning the message "myAge is not a function" but at least I'm closer.

Comment: @Autumn I tested it and I'm getting the age as '32' are you sure you are exactly writing what I have in my answer?

Comment: I think it may be the console I'm using because you're right, it does work on other consoles.

Comment: @Autumn I doubt if thats the case, maybe I can help if you show your entire file

Comment: @Autumn it's because you already have a variable named 'myAge' declared at the top. You have to either change the name of that variable or change the name of the function myAge()

Comment: @Autumn Glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

change Year() to Year. So it will be Year - birthYear

Comment: Thanks!  It's still returning the message "myAge is not a function" but I'll keep working at it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply return the age with one line

```
function myAge(birthYear) {
    return new Date().getFullYear() - birthYear;
}

myAge(1984);
```

If you want to display your age in the console or the document

you'll need to pass the function return value to a variable

```
var age = myAge(1984);
console.log(age);
```

will log `32`